# Does Nexus 7 2013 have 3G support?

Tags: nexus-7, 3g

Nexus 7 2013 has 4G support, but I can't find any information on 3G support. If I get a Nexus 7 4G model, can I use 3G?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current [New Nexus 7's only support wifi](https://play.google.com/store/devices/details?id=nexus_7_16gb_2013). They do not support any mobile data yet. But once they are released with mobile data support, you can count on them supporting older networks, like 3g (HSPA/HSPA+) as well as supporting 4g (LTE). LTE coverage is not wide enough for them to only support 4g.

Comment: At this very moment, Google offer nexus 7 4g model. Is it support old 3g network?

Comment: @mef_ NO, it doesn't.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but I'd be astonished if it _didn't_ support 3g, and 2g, and Edge.  I've never heard of a phone that didn't support the older, slower protocols.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to support ONLY 4G.

[Comparison of Nexus 7 2012 and 2013 versions](http://androidadvices.com/nexus-7-2012-vs-nexus-7-2013-specs-features-pricing-info/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does support 2G (GSM/EDGE) and 3G (UMTS/HSPA+).

Source: https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3248332

---

## Nexus 7 (2013) Tech Specs (LTE)

### North America and Japan:

GSM: 850/900/1800/1900 MHz

HSPA+: 850/900/1900/2100/AWS (1700/2100) MHz (Bands: 1/2/4/5/8)

LTE: 700/850/1700/1800/1900/2100 MHZ (Bands: 1/2/3/4/5/13/17)

### Rest of World:

GSM: 850/900/1800/1900 MHz

HSPA+: 850/900/1900/2100/AWS (1700/2100) MHz (Bands: 1/2/4/5/8)

LTE: 800/850/1700/1800/1900/2100/2600 MHz (Bands: 1/2/3/4/5/7/20)

---

Note that it appears that there are two Nexus 7 2013 LTE models, which differ in LTE bands, but UMTS and GSM bands appear the same.