# Can the Nexus 7 LTE connect to 3G networks?

Tags: nexus-7, 3g, sim-unlocking

Is it possible to connect to 3G networks with the Nexus 7 LTE? Is it possible with an unlocked device or only with limited networks or standards?

I've tried to Google it but no one seems to have ever mentioned it, except maybe a few people asking the exact same thing as I am now...

I've seen [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51412/does-nexus-7-2013-have-3g-support?rq=1), but it seems to be highly outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to connect to 3G networks.  I'm not sure who your carrier is, but if you are in an area where you cannot pick up LTE then 3G should be the fallback.  I used to work for Verizon Wireless and this is how all the 4G LTE phones and tablets worked.  In fact, when LTE first started rolling out it wasn't in most places, including the area where I worked.  People were buying LTE devices left and right and they ONLY operated on 3G until the LTE network got built out.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on network provider.

From [Nexus 7 2013 LTE Variant Available Now for $349](http://www.droid-life.com/2013/09/09/nexus-7-2013-lte-variant-available-now-for-349/):

> Keep in mind that you won’t be able to fall back to Verizon 3G at any time, but you can fall back to AT&T and T-Mobile HSPA should you choose their service.

From [Google's Nexus 7 with 4G is now available in the UK](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2295412/googles-nexus-7-with-4g-is-now-available-in-the-uk):

> Buying from O2 is a different story, however. The mobile operator is selling the new Nexus 7 for £319.99, complete with a free SIM and 2GB of 3G data.

Comment: They cannot be unlocked to allow them to be used on more networks?

Comment: They can be unlocked to work on more than one network but any device can only run on the frequencies it's radios use.  For example, in the US Verizon and At&t use different frequencies for their LTE, and Sprint uses yet another.  It just depends on what radios are in your device vs. what frequencies and technologies the carrier you want to use is running on.  Most devices can support a range of wireless technologies, but that doesn't necessarily mean they will run on the carrier you want to use.  The Nexus uses GSM radios, and VZW uses a CDMA 3G network.  This is why it won't get Verizon 3G.

Comment: @JeroenBollen See Roan's comment above.

Comment: Nexus 7 LTE is not locked to any networks.  iPads aren't locked, either.